# two queryForObject methods in JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I was looking at the Spring document. At  [Class JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Class-) page, I was a little confused because it seems that these two methods are doing the same thing. Both their purpose is to return an object formed from the SQL result.

```
<T> T queryForObject(java.lang.String sql, 
                     java.lang.Object[] args, 
                     RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
```

Query given SQL to create a prepared statement from SQL and a list of arguments to bind to the query, mapping a single result row to a Java object via a RowMapper.

```
<T> T queryForObject(java.lang.String sql, 
                     java.lang.Object[] args, 
                     java.lang.Class<T> requiredType)
```

Query given SQL to create a prepared statement from SQL and a list of arguments to bind to the query, expecting a result object.

## question

Do they have the same purpose like what I understand?

If so, why we need both of these methods?

if not, what the difference between them? Is there a typical scenario for each of them?

## answer

So from the answer we got right now.

The method with requiredType is for returning an object formed from the SQL result only.

The method with RowMapper allow us to 
1. returning an object formed from the SQL result and we don't need every variable of the class in result 
2. doing complex validation or formatting before assigning to result object which can be easily done in java than in SQL

thank you Raghu.

## If anyone have more insight, please go head. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One usecase would be with rowMapper we can customize result object preparation.

```
 @Override  
  public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {  
    Employee e=new Employee();  
    e.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
    e.setName(rs.getString(2));  
    e.setSalary(rs.getInt(3));
    //e.someNonSetterMethod(customize(rs.getString(4)));
    return e;  
}
```

Comment: so, there are two upsides to use rowMapper. 1. we don't need to have every variable in the sql result.  2.  we can do some extra operation.

Comment: Yes, Also some time you might need to do complex validation or formatting before assigning to result object which can be easily done in java than in SQL.

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the actual question.